# How to fix Asus Eee PC 900 startup issues after failure?

Tags: troubleshooting, power-supply, boot, netbook, power

My Asus Eee PC 900 shows no signs of life.

I push the power button and get no response from anything. No lights, no power, no boot-up screen.

It has been like this since I received it from a friend. I asked her what happened and she said that smoke came from the keyboard, it shut down and hasnt turned on since. I have tried removing and cleaning the RAM, the computer charger still connects and works, but the battery receives no charge and the computer won't power on.

Any ideas as to what is going on?

Answer (score 1):

It's dead, Jim. There's probably nothing you can do.

Its CPU (or some other component) overheated to the point of burning, which itself was probably caused by fan failure. You can identify the destroyed component(s) by the burn marks (usually white) and smell.